# Why is the PSPP program not present in the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa repository?

Tags: apt, ppa, repository, desktop-apps

The program for statistical analysis PSPP is very important for research, i concluded my post-graduation with it, using Ubuntu 19.10, but it's not present in the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS repository, so we can install it easily. Why?

Comment: It was built for focal, but *Removal requested on 2019-10-27*; but I cannot see why sorry.

Comment: A workaround is download the deb package of your architecture from the eoan release: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/eoan/universe/base/pspp and then install it with dpkg or directly with the gnome-software or the ubuntu-software if you have it installed.

Comment: @lestcape Thanks for that idea. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PSPP package was dropped from Debian, and thence from Ubuntu, due to a licensing problem.

See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=924937

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install an earlier version, pspp-1.2.0 by compiling from source code at http://ftp.wayne.edu/gnu/pspp/.  You'll probably have to install several dependencies which ./configure should tell you.  Be sure to use three separate steps when compiling, e.g. sudo ./configure, sudo make, and sudo make install, to ensure files are correctly written.  The latest version seems to have at least one dependency issue.

Comment: Would you consider expanding on this answer to give more details about the process?  It would be most helpful if you'd give us a step-by-step.  What exactly were the obstacles that you faced, and how exactly did you solve them?

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if it can help, but I solved the problem in my Ubuntu 20.04 by adding this line in my `sources.list`:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy main universe
```

Here some other repository: https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/pspp/download

Comment: This will make apt want to upgrade about half of your packages to the versions from 20.10, resulting in a frankensystem with unknown problems.