# How soon are packages updated to latest release?

Tags: package-management, 20.04

There is No PSPP, No xpdf No ............ for 20.04. How soon will they land in 20.04?
[image]

[image]

Comment: The meaning of "release" is that it is all released. Your mental model of how Ubuntu is published appears to be flawed.

Answer (score 0):

They will not: 20.04 is already complete and released.

New "Landings" will be for 20.10, to be released in October 2020.

During every cycle, some abandoned/broken/incompatible packages are dropped.

- Consider using the Search box at the top of the page to look for existing questions about each dropped package.
- See the existing [PSPP in 20.04 Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234137/why-is-the-pspp-program-not-present-in-the-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa-reposito)

For clues about why a package was dropped, look at the Debian Bugs page and the Debian Package Tracker.

- XPDF: [37 Outstanding bugs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?package=xpdf), and [No Package Maintainer](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/xpdf) (Orphaned in Debian).
- [Debian welcomes volunteers](http://mentors.debian.net) to adopt packages. YOU can learn how to get XPDF re-added to Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following link.Download it and install it.
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/eoan/universe/base/pspp

This  works great. I was also searching for PSPP but the old version just works fine in 20.04. Lets hope new version arrives